# How to check for false or undefined with strict-boolean-expressions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

We are using now the `@typescript-eslint` rule `strict-boolean-expressions` with this config:

Now I am looking for the right way to check if a boolean is false or undefined.

For example I have this case:

```
const foo = (myBoolean?: boolean) => {
  if (!myBoolean) console.log("myBoolean is false or undefined");
}
```

With the rule activated, I get this warning:
`Unexpected nullable boolean value in conditional. Please handle the nullish case explicitly.`

Should it be now:

`if (myBoolean === undefined || !myBoolean)`

Or is there a better practice?

Edit:

There is another case in React class components:

I have also another example with the state in a React class component:

```
interface IState {
    myBoolean?: boolean;
}

type IProps = React.PropsWithChildren<unknown>;

export class TestComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { myBoolean: false };
    }

    public componentDidMount(): void {
        if (!this.state.myBoolean) console.log("myBoolean", myBoolean);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <MyComponent />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd handle it by using a default value:

```typescript
const foo = (myBoolean: boolean = false) => {
    if (!myBoolean) {
        console.log("myBoolean is false or [was] undefined");
    }
};
```

In other situations where you can't or don't want to do that, if you want to use the rule, you could (as the warning said) use nullish coalescing:

```typescript
const foo = (myBoolean?: boolean) => {
    if (!(myBoolean ?? false)) {
        console.log("myBoolean is false or undefined");
    }
};
```

Comment: I wonder though, how do you pass `null` into the function [in the first place](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1&ssl=5&ssc=11&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBbAngIUQGwFMBDMAfgC4YAjAksAShQD4YBvAKBhgEs50AhNjwgipJqEijCAOnwgA5mgBEwuqV4R4xfBEIwQAJxgBXMABNCcHmELnlDANwcAvhw4IQaMCfz4nQA)? (v 3.5.1, but it also doesnt let this pass in the latest version)

Comment: @MikeS. - You can't, but you can leave off the argument or pass `undefined`. The "ish" in "nullish" is because `??` takes the right-hand value if the left-hand value is `null` *or* `undefined`. :-) The question was about `false` or `undefined`. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: That is a cool way! Don't thought about it. That solves my problems. The first way would be cool for my function. The second way is very nice for example state booleans in a React class component. I have this case, too! Thank you :)

Comment: @Tommy - Just FWIW, in the state example, I'd initialize it with `false` so the type is `boolean`, not `boolean | undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Iam not sure why eslint doesn't like this, `!myBoolean` does handle `null` yes, but it can't be `null` in the first place.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added a state example, where I'd initialize with `false` in the constructor, but the rule warning comes, too. Do you mean it in another way?

Comment: @Tommy - Don't my `myBoolean` optional in the interface. Just `myBoolean: boolean`.

Comment: @MikeS. - I think it's because it's not happy with using `!myBoolean` to check for `false` **or** `undefined` (because that's not strict enough for that check). It has nothing to do with `null`.

Comment: (Doh! I meant "don't *make* `myBoolean` optional in the interface..." :-) )